# df = pd.read_csv('file.csv') adds random numbers and commas to file. Pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file using pandas as so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Here is the file before:

```
,schoolId,Name,Meetings Present
0,991,Jimmy Nuetron,2
1,992,Jimmy Fuetron,6
2,993,Cam Nuetron,4
```

Here is the file after:

```
,Unnamed: 0,schoolId,Name,Meetings Present
0,0.0,991.0,Jimmy Nuetron,2.0
1,1.0,992.0,Jimmy Fuetron,6.0
2,2.0,993.0,Cam Nuetron,4.0
0,,,,3
```

Why is it adding the numbers and columns when I run the read_csv method?

How can I prevent this without adding a seperator?

Answer (score 0):

[**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is actuallly not adding the column `Unnamed: 0` because it already exists in your `.csv` (who apparently/probably was generated by the method [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)).

You can get rid of this (extra) column by making it as an index :

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
```